# Android Grade could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgrade this Modular project to latest dependencies but gradle build fails with `could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2` I have aleady included `mavenCentral()` to repositories but doesn't seem to help.

Note: same versions work on different app with monolithic architecture, not sure modular architecture has anything to do with it.

**app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${Versions.gradle}"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:${Versions.nav}"
}
}
```

**buildSrc/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
`kotlin-dsl`
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**dependencies.kts**

```
object Versions {
const val kotlin = "1.6.10"
const val gradle = "7.0.2"
const val room = "2.4.2"
...
}

object Libraries {
    const val roomCompiler = "androidx.room:room-compiler:${Versions.room}"
    const val roomRunTime = "androidx.room:room-runtime:${Versions.room}"
    const val roomKtx = "androidx.room:room-ktx:${Versions.room}"
...
}
```

Here is a link to my [Git Repo](https://github.com/pouriabagheri/ArchApp/tree/upgrade)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I've clone your repository in `upgrade` branch. It seems the module doesn't get the repository.

It's because your `:data:model` module is used as plain kotlin project, and it can't implement room library. In fact, many of your module is not registered as Android Library.

---

If you intent to use the module to setup Android configuration or use android library like room, please implement library plugin in your `build.gradle`.

I suppose you can implement "com.android.library" to all your modules first, and please for the love of god... do a better gradle configuration for your modules.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that and I have already replaced jcenter with google() and mavenCentral() and it did not resolve the issue

Comment: did you try master branch or upgrade ? because the master branch is running the old version that uses jcenter and it works fine